# How to use yaml.load_all with fileinput.input?

Tags: python, pyyaml

Without resorting to `''.join`, is there a Pythonic way to use PyYAML's `yaml.load_all` with `fileinput.input()` for easy streaming of multiple documents from multiple sources?

I'm looking for something like the following (non-working example):

```
# example.py
import fileinput

import yaml

for doc in yaml.load_all(fileinput.input()):
    print(doc)
```

Expected output:

```
$ cat >pre.yaml <<<'--- prefix-doc'
$ cat >post.yaml <<<'--- postfix-doc'
$ python example.py pre.yaml - post.yaml <<<'--- hello'
prefix-doc
hello
postfix-doc
```

Of course, `yaml.load_all` expects either a string, bytes, or a file-like object and `fileinput.input()` is none of those things, so the above example does not work.

Actual output:

```
$ python example.py pre.yaml - post.yaml <<<'--- hello'
...
AttributeError: FileInput instance has no attribute 'read'
```

You can make the example work with `''.join`, but that's cheating. I'm looking for a way that does not read the entire stream into memory at once.

We might rephrase the question as *Is there some way to emulate a string, bytes, or file-like object that proxies to an underlying iterator of strings?* However, I doubt that `yaml.load_all` actually needs the entire file-like interface, so that phrasing would ask for more than is strictly necessary.

Ideally I'm looking for the minimal adapter that would support something like this:

```
for doc in yaml.load_all(minimal_adapter(fileinput.input())):
    print(doc)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `minimal_adapter` should take a `fileinput.FileInput` as a parameter and return an object which `load_all` can use. `load_all` either takes as an argument a string, but that would require concatenating the input, or it expects the argument to have a `read()` method.

Since your minimal_adapter needs to preserve some state, I find it clearest/easiest to implement it as an instance of a class that has a `__call__` method, and have that method return the instance and store its argument for future use. Implemented that way, the class should also have a `read()` method, as this will be called after handing the instance to `load_all`:

```
import fileinput
import ruamel.yaml


class MinimalAdapter:
    def __init__(self):
        self._fip = None
        self._buf = None  # storage of read but unused material, maximum one line

    def __call__(self, fip):
        self._fip = fip  # store for future use
        self._buf = ""
        return self

    def read(self, size):
        if len(self._buf) >= size:
            # enough in buffer from last read, just cut it off and return
            tmp, self._buf = self._buf[:size], self._buf[size:]
            return tmp
        for line in self._fip:
            self._buf += line
            if len(self._buf) > size:
                break
        else:
            # ran out of lines, return what we have
            tmp, self._buf = self._buf, ''
            return tmp
        tmp, self._buf = self._buf[:size], self._buf[size:]
        return tmp


minimal_adapter = MinimalAdapter()

for doc in ruamel.yaml.load_all(minimal_adapter(fileinput.input())):
    print(doc)
```

With this, running your example invocation exactly gives the output that you want.

This is probably only more memory efficient for larger files. The `load_all` tries to read 1024 byte blocks at a time (easily found out by putting a print statement in `MinimalAdapter.read()`) and `fileinput` does some buffering as well (use `strace` if your interested to find out how it behaves).

---

<sub>This was done using [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) a YAML 1.2 parser, of which I am the author. This should work for PyYAML, of which ruamel.yaml is a derived superset, as well.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The problem with `fileinput.input` is that the resulting object doesn't have a `read` method, which is what `yaml.load_all` is looking for.  If you're willing to give up `fileinput`, you can just write your own class that will do what you want:

```
import sys                                                                      
import yaml                                                                     

class BunchOFiles (object):                                                     
    def __init__(self, *files):                                                 
        self.files = files                                                      
        self.fditer = self._fditer()                                            
        self.fd = self.fditer.next()                                            

    def _fditer(self):                                                          
        for fn in self.files:                                                   
            with sys.stdin if fn == '-' else open(fn, 'r') as fd:               
                yield fd                                                        

    def read(self, size=-1):                                                    
        while True:                                                             
            data = self.fd.read(size)                                           

            if data:                                                            
                break                                                           
            else:                                                               
                try:                                                            
                    self.fd = self.fditer.next()                                
                except StopIteration:                                           
                    self.fd = None                                              
                    break                                                       

        return data                                                             

bunch = BunchOFiles(*sys.argv[1:])                                              
for doc in yaml.load_all(bunch):                                                
    print doc
```

The `BunchOFiles` class gets you an object with a `read` method that will happily iterate over a list of files until everything is exhausted.  Given the above code and your sample input, we get exactly the output you're looking for.

Comment: This is a good answer and I wish I could mark multiple answers as accepted ("✅ Acceptable"?); however, another answer reuses `fileinput` as-is without reimplementing or replacing any of it, which I think aligns closer to this question's intention of minimal. I can see how this answer meets a _different kind_ of minimal though, so thank you for contributing!